# In perl6, how do you read a file in paragraph mode?

Tags: file, io, raku

data.txt:

```
hello world
goodbye mars

goodbye perl6
hello perl5
```

myprog.py:

```
my $fname = 'data.txt';
my $infile = open($fname, :r, nl => "\n\n");

for $infile.lines(nl => "\n\n") -> $para {
    say $para;
    say '-' x 10;
}
```

Actual output:

```
hello world
----------
goodbye mars
----------

----------
goodbye perl6
----------
back to perl5
----------
```

Desired output:

```
hello world
goodbye mars
-----------
goodbye perl6
back to perl5
-----------
```

...

```
$ perl6 -v
This is perl6 version 2015.03-21-gcfa4974 built on MoarVM version 2015.03
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Rakudo/MoarVM, going back to the fact that MoarVM expects a single grapheme as separator instead of an arbitrary string (cf [syncfile.c:38](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/2015.03/src/io/syncfile.c#L38), [syncfile.c:119](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/2015.03/src/io/syncfile.c#L119) and [syncfile.c:91](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/2015.03/src/io/syncfile.c#L91), which shows that the last character of the separator string is used instead of the whole string).

As a quick workaround (but beware that this reads the entire file into memory), use

```
$fname.IO.slurp.split("\n\n")
```

instead of `$infile.lines()`.

You should also file a bug report or ask in `#perl6` on Freenode if this is a known issue.

Comment: At irc #perl6, they patched the docs to delete the :nl parameter from the lines() definition, and they told me to file a bug report for open(), which I did: https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/issues/193.